# Javascript Calling a nested function from within itself

Tags: javascript, function, methods, nested, closures

If I run the following...

```
function outer(){
    function inner(){
    }

    inner();
}
```

inner will run the first time as expected.

---

If I then try to run the following...

```
function outer(){
    function inner(){
        inner();
    }

    inner();
}
```

inner will again run the first time as expected, but then fails at any subsequent attempts, returning the error: ReferenceError: inner is not defined

---

If I expose the function to the global namespace it will work again...

```
function outer(){
    function inner(){
        inner();
    }

    window.inner = inner;
    inner();
}
```

**Is there a way to reference the nested function from within itself WITHOUT adding it to the global namespace?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign the function to a local variable within the execution scope

```
function outer() {
    var inner;

    inner = function () {
        inner();
    }
    inner();
}
```

Comment: hm, I am still receiving 'inner is not defined' error message. I am calling inner from a setTimeout inside inner if that makes a difference.

Comment: Are you using quotes for the setTimeout? you don't need to, you can just pass any function instance.